# Favorites offers with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have Offers table and Favorites table with offer_id.
When I display all Offers at the screen
I want to display "yellow star" in favorites offers

I get Favorites as:

```
  scope :in_favorites, lambda { |user_id|
    favorites = Favorite.where(:user_id => user_id).map(&:offer_id)
    if favorites.size > 0
      where :id => favorites
    end
  }
```

How to check if Offer exists in Favorites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but your should be able to check if an offer is in the favorites of an user with :

```
# Example with the user n°1
Offer.in_favorites(1).include?(offer)
```

Another way to model your offers would be to use a `has_many :through` association :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :favorites
    has_many :favorite_offers, :through => :favorites, :source => :offer
end
```

You could then do :

```
# user is an instance of User
user.favorite_offers.include?(offer)

# same thing, only SQL. A bit less readable, but doesn't load all the user's favorites
!user.favorite_offers.where(:id => offer.id).empty?
```

Hope this helps.